# Complement to GetCommandLine for getting the argument count?

Tags: c++, winapi

Working in Windows C++ and using `GetCommandLine` to get the arguments in a function. Is there a similar function which would return the number of arguments in the command line?

I am unable to get it from main because I am using the

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/, 
    HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, 
    LPTSTR /*lpCmdLine*/, 
    int /*nShowCmd*/)
```

main function.

Comment: you're getting 1 argument: all of it. you have to parse the string yourself

Comment: I think you're looking for `CommandLineToArgvW`.

Comment: If using Microsoft's VC++ compiler (and CRT) version 2013 or later check out [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674.aspx).

Comment: @dxiv good answer but for completeness let mention that those are available only since [2013 compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: @mvidelgauz Good point. I updated the previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way is to use another API with GetCommandLine

```
int numArgs = 0;
LPCWSTR *argv[] = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &numArgs);
```

Now in numArgs a count of arguments, in argv a pointer to an array of arguments. CRT startup code uses this function to build argv

argv[0] is a name of module, argv[n], with n > 0 is a arguments of line, stripped by space